# PowerShell: Catch errors but continue without loop?

Tags: powershell, try-catch

I like to think I'm pretty good with PowerShell, but I'm a bit stumped here.

I have a GIANT list of files that I'm going to run this code on that will give me some necessary file information that I'll run analytics on. Step one is just getting the file list. So I run this.

```
Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse
```

This returns a bunch of useless information, BUT it also gives me a sea of red. There's tons of files and folders that cannot be found and explicitly deny me. I want to catch all of these errors so I can parse them down to relevant information, so my gut feeling tells me to use Try/Catch.

Normally you use Try/Catch to store error messages within a loop somewhere outside of the loop, and that works great. But I don't actually have a loop to Continue on. I'm not sure what to do now. Here's the source code I have.

```
function Get-FileInfo {
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=0)]
        [ValidateNotNull()]
        [string]$path
    )

    $global:errorInfo = @()
    Write-Host "I started!"

    Try {
        Write-Host "I started the Try Statement!"
        $fileInfo = Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse -ErrorAction Stop
        Write-Host "I finished the main pull!"
        Return $fileInfo
    }

    Catch {
        Write-Host "I started the Catch Statement!"
        $errorObj = New-Object PSObject
        Add-Member -inputObject $errorObj -memberType NoteProperty -name “Type” -value $_.Exception.Message
        Add-Member -inputObject $errorObj -memberType NoteProperty -name “Item” -value $_.Exception.ItemName
        $errorInfo += $errorObj
        Continue
    }

}
```

I'm sure you see the issue. I want to capture the errors that will inevitably occur within the Try block, but I don't actually have a loop. I don't really see how to set this up as a loop to make things better.

If I run this code, it will write "I Started!" and then "I started the Try Statement" almost immediately after that. Then it will work for about a minute. Then I get a "I started the Catch statement!" and it immediately ends. It makes sense why that happens, but that's obviously not the intended result.

Am I just thinking about this wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The errors you're describing are *non-terminating* errors, which you can collect in 
a variable with the [common `-ErrorVariable` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#errorvariable), without stopping the command on the first error (which is what `-ErrorAction Stop` does).

```
# Silence non-terminating errors and collect them in variable $errs
Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable errs
```

- Note how the target variable name, `errs` must be specified *without the `$`*, since you're passing the variable's *name*, not its value. `$errs` is created as a *local* variable.

  - It's generally better to avoid setting variables across scope boundaries, but it *is* possible to target a variable in the *script* scope / *global* scope instead, namely with
    `-ErrorVariable script:errs` / `-ErrorVariable global:errs`
- To also *silence* the errors, use `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` , not `-ErrorAction Ignore` - the latter would suppress errors altogether, making `$errs` empty.

Comment: I tried this exact code, but my error variable remains null. I know there are errors though. Does it have something to do with being a global variable? Does -ErrorVariable create a local variable?

Comment: @lordsampigans: Yes, `-ErrorVariable` creates a _local_ variable by default, but you can use a scope modifier, if needed - please see my update.